# Speed up simple Python function that uses list comprehension

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7

I'm extracting 4 columns from an imported CSV file (~500MB) to be used for fitting a `scikit-learn` regression model.

It seems that this function used to do the extraction is extremely slow. I just learnt python today, any suggestions on how the function can be sped up?

Can multithreading/core be used? My system has 4 cores.

```
def splitData(jobs):
    salaries = [jobs[i]['salaryNormalized'] for i, v in enumerate(jobs)]
    descriptions = [jobs[i]['description'] + jobs[i]['normalizedLocation'] + jobs[i]['category'] for i, v in enumerate(jobs)]
    titles = [jobs[i]['title'] for i, v in enumerate(jobs)]

    return salaries, descriptions, titles
```

**print type(jobs)**

```
<type 'list'>
```

**print jobs[:1]**

`[{'category': 'Engineering Jobs', 'salaryRaw': '20000 - 30000/annum 20-30K', 'rawLocation': 'Dorking, Surrey, Surrey', 'description': 'Engineering Systems Analyst Dorking Surrey Salary ****K Our client is located in Dorking, Surrey and are looking for Engineering Systems Analyst our client provides specialist software development Keywords Mathematical Modelling, Risk Analysis, System Modelling, Optimisation, MISER, PIONEEER Engineering Systems Analyst Dorking Surrey Salary ****K', 'title': 'Engineering Systems Analyst', 'sourceName': 'cv-library.co.uk', 'company': 'Gregory Martin International', 'contractTime': 'permanent', 'normalizedLocation': 'Dorking', 'contractType': '', 'id': '12612628', 'salaryNormalized': '25000'}]`

---

```
def loadData(filePath):
    reader = csv.reader( open(filePath) )
    rows = []

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        categories = ["id", "title", "description", "rawLocation", "normalizedLocation",
                        "contractType", "contractTime", "company", "category",
                        "salaryRaw", "salaryNormalized","sourceName"]

        # Skip header row
        if i != 0: 
            rows.append( dict(zip(categories, row)) )

    return rows



def splitData(jobs):
    salaries = []
    descriptions = []
    titles = []

    for i in xrange(len(jobs)):
        salaries.append( jobs[i]['salaryNormalized'] )
        descriptions.append( jobs[i]['description'] + jobs[i]['normalizedLocation'] + jobs[i]['category'] )
        titles.append( jobs[i]['title'] )

    return salaries, descriptions, titles



def fit(salaries, descriptions, titles):
    #Vectorize
    vect = TfidfVectorizer()
    vect2 = TfidfVectorizer()
    descriptions = vect.fit_transform(descriptions)
    titles = vect2.fit_transform(titles)

    #Fit
    X = hstack((descriptions, titles))
    y = [ np.log(float(salaries[i])) for i, v in enumerate(salaries) ]

    rr = Ridge(alpha=0.035)
    rr.fit(X, y)

    return vect, vect2, rr, X, y



jobs = loadData( paths['train_data_path'] )
salaries, descriptions, titles = splitData(jobs)
vect, vect2, rr, X_train, y_train = fit(salaries, descriptions, titles)
```

Comment: How about using generator expressions here?  `y=(x for x in someList)`

Comment: Python's multicore capabilities are extremely weak. But I don't think that's the issue at all. What kind of object is `jobs`?

Comment: @larsmans `jobs` are `lists` type.

Comment: Alright. And where is the result going? To a `DictVectorizer`?

Comment: @larsmans Yup, `descriptions = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(descriptions)`

Comment: This probably won't help with the long time, but all your list comprehensions could be written in the form of `[job['salaryNormalized'] for job in jobs]`, which is probably slightly faster and just better code.

Answer (score 2):

I see multiple problems with your code, directly impacting its performance.

1. You `enumerate` the jobs list multiple times. You could enumerate it only once and instead use the enumerated list (stored in a variable).
2. You don't use the value from the enumerated items at all. All you need is the index, and you could easily achieve this using the built-in `range` function.
3. Each of the lists is generated in eager manner. What happens is the following: 1st list blocks the execution of the program and it takes some time to finish. Same thing happens with the second and third lists, where calculations are exactly the same.

What I would offer you to do, is to use a generator, so that you process the data in a lazy manner. It's more performance-efficient and allows you to extract the data on-the-go.

```
def splitData(jobs):
    for job in jobs:
        yield job['salaryNormalized'], job['description'] + job['normalizedLocation'] + job['category'], job['title']
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple speedup is to cut down on your list traversals.  You can build a generator or generator expression that returns tuples for a single dictionary, then zip the resulting iterable:

```
(salaries, descriptions, titles) = zip(*((j['salaryNormalized'], j['description'] + j['normalizedLocation'] + j['category'], j['title']) for j in jobs))
```

Unfortunately, that still creates three sizable in-memory lists - using a generator expression rather than a list comprehension should at least prevent it from creating a full list of three-element tuples prior to zipping.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that `TfidVectorizer` accepts an iterator (e.g. generator expression) as well. This helps prevent having multiple copies of this rather large data in memory, which probably is what makes it slow. Alternatively, for sure it can work with files directly. One could transform the csv into separate files and then feed those files to `TfidVectorizer` directly without keeping them in memory in any way at all.

**Edit 1**

Now that you provided some more code, I can be a bit more specific.

First of all, please note that `loadData` is doing more than it needs to; it duplicates functionality present in `csv.DictReader`. If we use that, we skip the listing of category names. Another syntax for opening files is used, because in this way, they're closed automatically. Also, some names are changed to be both more accurate and Pythonic (underscore style).

```
def data_from_file(filename):
    rows = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            rows.append(row)
    return rows
```

We can now change this so that we don't build the list of all rows in memory, but instead give back a row one at a time right after we read it from the file. If this looks like magic, just read a little about generators in Python.

```
def data_from_file(path):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield row
```

Now let's have a look at `splitData`. We could write it more cleanly like this:

```
def split_data(jobs):
    salaries = []
    descriptions = []
    titles = []

    for job in jobs:
        salaries.append(job['salaryNormalized'] )
        descriptions.append(job['description'] + job['normalizedLocation'] + 
                            job['category'])
        titles.append(job['title'])

    return salaries, descriptions, titles
```

But again we don't want to build three huge lists in memory. And generally, it's not going to be practical that this function gives us three different things. So to split it up:

```
def extract_salaries(jobs):
    for job in jobs:
        yield job['salaryNormalized']
```

And so on. This helps us set up some kind of processing pipeline; everytime we'd request a value from `extract_salaries(data_from_file(filename))` a single line of the csv would be read and the `salary` extracted. The next time, the second line giving back the second `salary`. There's no need to make functions for this simple case. Instead, you can use a generator expression:

```
salaries = (job['salaryNormalized'] for job in data_from_file(filename))
descriptions = (job['description'] + job['normalizedLocation'] +
                job['category'] for job in data_from_file(filename))
titles = (job['title'] for job in data_from_file(filename))
```

You can now pass these generators to `fit`, where the most important modification is this:

```
y = [np.log(float(salary)) for salary in salaries]
```

You can't index into an iterator (something that gives you one value at a time) so you just assume you will get a `salary` from `salaries` as long as there are more, and do something with it.

In the end, you will read the whole csv file multiple times, but I don't expect that to be the bottleneck. Otherwise, some more restructuring is required.

**Edit 2**

Using `DictReader` seems a bit slow. Not sure why, but you may stick with your own implementation of that (modified to be a generator) or even better, go with `namedtuple`s:

```
def data_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = reader.next()
        Job = namedtuple('Job', header)
        for row in reader:
            yield Job(*row)
```

Then access the attributes with a dot (`job.salaryNormalized`). But anyway note that you can get the list of column names from the file; don't duplicate it in code.

You may of course decide to keep a single copy of the file in memory after all. In that case, do something like this:

```
data = list(data_from_file(filename))
salaries = (job['salaryNormalized'] for job in data)
```

The functions remain untouched. The call to `list` consumes the whole generator and stores all values in a `list`.

Comment: I've updated the question with more code. I am also unsure of how a generator can be created and used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the indexes at all. Just use `in`. This saves the creation of a extra list of tuples, and it removes a level of indirection;

```
salaries = [j['salaryNormalized'] for j in jobs]
descriptions = [j['description'] + j['normalizedLocation'] + j['category'] for j in jobs]
titles = [j['title'] for j in jobs]
```

This still iterates over the data three times.

Alternatively you could get everything in one list comprehension, grouping the relevant data from one job together in a tuple;

```
data = [(j['salaryNormalized'], 
         j['description'] + j['normalizedLocation'] + j['category'],
         j['title']) for j in jobs]
```

Saving the best for last; why not fill the lists straight from the CSV file instead of making a dict first?

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as df:
    reader = csv.reader(df)
    # I made up the row indices...
    data = [(row[1], row[3]+row[7]+row[6], row[2]) for row in reader]
```